# Бургер меню перекрывает стрелочку "назад"

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Имеется следующий код

***MainActivity***

Эта часть (1) объявляет toolbar и создаёт кнопку назад

```
    // toolbar
(1) Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Эта часть (2) отвечает за бургер меню и выдвижение шторки

```
(2) DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Если оставить только первую (1) часть кода то мы увидим следующую картину

[image: только первая часть кода]

Если добавить вторую (2) часть кода то стрелку как я понимаю перекрывает бургер меню и мы видим следующую картину

[image: бургер меню]

**Вопрос в том** как сделать так, чтобы бургер меню показывалось только на основном экране, а при переходе по фрагментам появлялась стрелочка "Назад", если что я использовал стандартный шаблон android studio "Navigation Drawer". Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Мне кажется, вы не совсем поняли суть этого UI шаблона. Все работает как и должно. Запускайте новую активити и будет вам стрелочка. В активити где есть бургер, стрелка только для закрытия шторки, не для навигации.

Comment: Перропределить то что надо в нужных фрагмертах.